Closed geodesics of a non positively curved manifold are minimizing
As the title says, closed geodesics of a complete non positive sectional curvature manifold should be minimal in their free homotopy class.
This should be well known but I don't know a reference.
I can imagine at least two proofs: using flat strip theorem or using Morse theory. Neither are very simple, so a reference would be preferred.

You only need to know that the orthogonal projection to geodesics in Hadamard manifolds is distance-nonincreasing. As for the result itself, check Ballmann-Gromov-Schroeder.

I don't know what you mean, also which result do you mean?

I mean minimality of closed geodesics.

I cannot find it there.

See Lemma 6.5, Part 2.

Consider a closed geodesic $\gamma\subseteq M$.  Then its lift to the universal cover $\tilde M$ is an infinite geodesic.
For your question it is sufficient to show that in the universal cover, which is an Hadamard manifold, infinite geodesics are lines, i.e., are globally distance-minimizing.
In a general Riemannian manifold, the cut locus of a point $p$ consists of two sorts of points $q$: either (1) conjugate points to $p$ along some geodesic, or (2) there are two distinct minimizing geodesics from $p$ to $q$.
In an Hadamard manifold, elementary considerations with Jacobi fields show that conjugate points don't exist.
Furthermore, in such a situation the point $q$ of the cut locus which is nearest to $p$ (such a $q$ exists by completeness) has the property that there is a pair of minimizing geodesics from $p$ to $q$ which join to form a geodesic loop at $p$, i.e., they connect up smoothly at $q$.  But this contradicts the fact that in an Hadamard manifold, the exponential map is a global diffeomorphism.
Now suppose $\gamma$ could be shortened in its free homotopy class to a shorter loop $\delta$.  Choose a point on $\gamma$ and lift $\gamma$ to a path starting at $p$ in the universal cover, with endpoint $g(p)$ where $g$ is an element of the fundamental group (acting on $\tilde M$).  We already established that the distance $d(p,g^n(p))$ is precisely $n\,d(p,g(p))$.  Now if $\delta$ is shorter than $\gamma$, then lifting it to a path from $q$ to $g(q)$ would give a slower rate of growth, namely $n\,d(q,g(q))$.  Since $d(g^n(p),g^n(q))$ is constant (independent of $n$), this contradicts the minimality of $\tilde\gamma$.

I meant free homotopy class (added free for emphasis), your argument only shows minimizing property in a based homotopy class.

What's the equivalence? Also your statements are ambiguous. On the universal cover geodesic segments are minimizing, relative end points. it makes no sense to say that geodesics themselves are minimizing.

Consider the flat cone with vertex removed. This is not complete, but it doesn't matter for your idea I think. On the universal cover geodesic segments are globally minimal. But they never project to minimal closed geodesics,.

You only  "used" only minimality of segments, this still holds in the above example. More to the point you give no proof at all of the needed implication. How does minimality of segments upstairs imply what we want.

I added a clarification (these arguments are pretty standard so I initially thought you were familiar with them).

Ok, that looks more reasonable, I will think about it when I get a moment, thanks.

That works I think, so this actually indirectly proves that any geodesic ray on the cone must go to the singularity.
